# Does spring retry dependency covered under spring batch in spring initializr?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-retry, spring-initializr

Trying to add Retry dependency in spring initializr, but only batch is showed?
Does it mean need to add spring-batch and use retry?

Comment: I do confirm, I only see spring batch when I search for retry. It looks like this option was added in https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/149 but it does not show up anymore (I'm not sure if this is a regression or a deliberate decision to remove it).

Answer (score 0):

No. Not every possible modules that the Spring ecosystem has is on start.spring.io. We try to reduce things to what's relevant for a getting started experience.

With a project generated on start.spring.io, you already get dependency management for Spring Retry so, if you prefer to use it directly without Spring Batch or another module that uses it, you can add the jar directly. You don't need to specify a version as this is taken care for you.